# Error inserting images to posts with TinyMCE in PODS Wordpress Framework

Tags: wordpress, tinymce, podscms

I have problem with an installation of PODS Framework in Wordpress with tinymce helper.

When I’m trying to upload new image (by using media upload button) it works fine, however when I’m trying to insert image to post I get a javascript error which says missing insertContent method on QTags.

I saw that Pods-tinymce has its own version of this js class and I didn’t see insertContent function in this file?

Any ideas what should I check now?

Comment: Did you end up figuring this out? Is it solved with Pods 2.0?

Answer (score 0):

You may add content using the `mceInsertContent` execCommand:

```
tinyMCE.execCommand('mceInsertContent', false, '<img src="..." href="..."/>');
```